# speeding up NSMutableArray declaration?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to speed up declaration of a 2d array and the following "example" is too slow where allocation is done as it comes. How can I do the allocation 10 columns where each column may have up to 20 elements... letting the remainders be nil/null.  Is there automation for this or do I have to loop through each column and addObjects(SLOW) and init with 20 objects of nil?

```
ppp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 10];

[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"1",
                    @"2",
                    @"3",
                    @"4",
                    nil
                    ]];

[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"a1",
                    @"b2",
                    @"c3",
                    nil
                    ]];
```

thanks...

(let me put it this way:  in "standard-c" I can declare "*char person[100][100]"... declaration of space is done.  Now just write to the addresses.  Dynamical allocation is a lot of row swapping that is cpu and memory consuming.  Is there anything in "Objective-c" to accomplish something that does NSArray *person[100][100] ?? )

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." --Donald Knuth

Comment: What do you mean by "too slow"? You mean there's too much code to write? Or you've measured it and it actually executes too slowly for what you need? (using NSArrays for a 10x20 2d thing seems silly but certainly not "slow" by any reasonable measure) If so, please also explain what the context is so we can help you create a more appropriate data structure.

Comment: this was a snippet of a significantly much larger 2d array.  Dynamic allocation is super slow for large matrices.  And when processing with subsets, this is a bottleneck in time and cpu.

Comment: OK. Then please spend some time explaining the context of the problem. How big are they? What kinds of things are you storing in them? How and how often will you access them? Etc. And if the dynamic allocation is "super slow", what *are* your performance requirements? (Plain old 2-D C-style arrays are still available if they fit the bill for you, though if you're keeping Obj-C objects in them you'll need to manage that memory manually with some wrapper code.)

Comment: people here are telling me to steer away from "standard-c" and use "objective-c" due to it being "easier" on the iPhone etc.

Comment: Kristen, I'd like to help but please consider asking a clearer question here. You've given a made-up example and claimed that it's "too slow", without saying what your actual data looks like, what it's doing, or what your actual performance requirements are. I'll believe you that nested NSArrays may not be an ideal solution for you, but until you articulate what your requirements really are, any advice people give will be just random ideas.

Comment: in "standard-c":   "*char person[100][100]" is simple to declare and allocate memory right away... no shifting around.  What in "objective-c" does this?

Comment: @Kristen: Nothing in Cocoa does that. What "shifting around" are you concerned about, and why, specifically, are you concerned?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array of arrays, as you do, why don't you use a single NSMutableArray and calculate the rows and columns? I know that your 2d array is ragged, i.e. each "sub"array may have a different length, but you could calculate the max. "width" and max "height" of your table and simply leave some items free:

```
ppp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"", @"",
    @"a1", @"b2", @"c3", @"", @"", @"",
    etc...
    ];
```

Now you simply calculate item[1,2] as itemAt: 6*1 + 2.

Not sure if that helps, but it might speed up things.

An alternative is to use simple C arrays instead.

Comment: definitely this is a good approach for some stuff... but I am trying to take advantage of some of the NS-class features per array-column.

Comment: That may be, but then I must agree with quixoto: you don't give enough details to help you with the speed problem. It would help to know what you want to do with the single NSMutableArrays in the main one. Do the advantages of having them grouped in their own arrays weigh up against the speed disadvantage? Etc.etc. All things we can't see from here.